# how to change the line wrap setting of Black (Python formatter)?

Tags: python, formatter

I'm using black as my python formatter, and when there's a long list in my code, black will format this list, causes it takes much lines to place this list like this :

```py
city_order_list = [
    1,
    22,
    8,
    26,
    31,
    3,
    36,
    35,
    20,
    2,
    29,
    21,
    ...
]
```

Is there any setting to disable this feature, or other advanced settings like specifying a fixed amount of elements in one line? Just like this:

```py
city_order_list = [
    1, 22, 8, 26, 31,
    28, 3, 36, 35, 20,
    2, 29, 21, 16, 50,
    34, 30, 9, 49, 10,
    39, 33, 45, 15, 44,
    42, 40, 19, 41, 13,
    25, 14, 24, 43, 7,
]
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and [documentation](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Black [documentation](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html#code-style), you can put `# fmt: off` before your lines of code and end it with `# fmt: on`. Or `# fmt: skip` for single lines. Also, `# fmt: on/off` have to be on the same level of indentation.